# How to access multiple servers with local DNS

Tags: networking, router, dns, webserver, synology

I want to access different services / web sites with a domain from my local computer, but also from over the internet.

---

**My network setup**:

[image: Network setup]
I run a local DNS on my Synology DS216j with the new DSM 6.1.
I have configured my local DNS to resolve `cloud.mydomain.com` and `web.mydomain.com`.

My router is a TP-Link Archer 2600.

On the DynDNS from [noip.com](http://noip.com) I have created an **A-Host** entry that points to my external IP from my local network.

---

**What I tried:**

When I enter `cloud.mydomain.com` on my local computer (*PC 1*) the local DNS redirects me to the correct website. The same for `web.mydomain.com`.

But when I try enter `cloud.mydomain.com` or `web.mydomain.com` on an external computer over the internet (*PC 2*) I get a timout.

When I configure for example a port forward for the port 80 to `cloud.mydomain.com` I can access to local server. But only that server then, whether I enter cloud.mydomain.com or `web.domain.com`.

**What do I need to configure to access my local servers from a computer over the internet?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use another public IP, so DNS records for cloud.mydomain.com will point to an IP1 and web.mydomain.com will point to IP2.

Another option is to use a reverse proxy, so both cloud.mydomain.com and web.mydomain.com will point to the same IP, port 80 will be forwarded to a reverse proxy in your local network and reverse proxy will forward HTTP requests based on the domain name in the HTTP GET to either cloud or www servers.

Comment: **Reverse proxy** is the key word. I added for now a reverse proxy in the Synology DSM a [tutorial](https://stefandingemanse.nl/configure-reverse-proxy-synology-nas-dsm-6-beta-2/).